# Being additive map using spectral decomposition theorem

Tags: von-neumann-algebras, decomposition-theorem

Let $(\mathcal{A},\tau_\mathcal{A})$ and $(\mathcal{B},\tau_\mathcal{B})$ be semifinite von Neumann algebras with normal semifinite faithful traces $\tau_\mathcal{A}$ and $\tau_\mathcal{B}$. I defined a map $\phi$ on $\tau_\mathcal{A}$-finite projections of $\mathcal{A}$ such that $\phi(e+f)=\phi(e)+\phi(f)$ whenver $ef=0$ (=orthogonal projections).

Recall that a self-adjoint simple operator is of the form $x=\sum_{n=1}^N \alpha_n e_n$, where $\alpha_n$’s are real and $e_n$’s are $\tau_{\mathcal{A}}$-finite projections with $e_n e_m=0$ whenever $n\neq m$.

I lift $\phi$ to self-adjoint simple operators by letting $\phi(x):=\sum_{n=1}^N\alpha_n \phi(e_n)$, for a self-adjoint simple operator $x=\sum_{n=1}^N\alpha_n e_n$.

Is there a way to show that $\phi(x+y)=\phi(x)+\phi(y)$ for commuting self-adjoint simple operators $x,y\in\mathcal{A}$, perhaps using the spectral decomposition theorem.

Comment: If $x$ and $y$ commute then so do their spectral projections. Use this to show that you can write $x = \sum_1^N \alpha_n e_n$ and $y=\sum_1^N \beta_n e_n$ (same $N$, same $e_n$'s). From there the desired conclusion follows easily.